# gerrit setup git repo -- permission denied

Tags: git, gerrit, public-key

I am new to gerrit, and I am now trying to setup gerrit a git project.I am now searching help for resolving a permission denied issue, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

I am using gerrit + http + mysql, I am now have following problem:

1. As I checked my database, I can not find 'login_type' and 'login_http_head' from "system_config" in my database, which is described http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r243/documentation/2.0/config-sso.html
2. When I click admin->projects, a prompt said "missing project all-projects"
3. When I checked my accounts from database, there are two empty users (I think it's because I did not set them in the UIweb page)
4. I cannot register new accounts from UIweb page, I cannot use command line create new users also.

Following are my steps for ssh-key and register:

1. I used `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048`  (Searchign from internet, I don't know what does 2048 mean)
2. I use `git config` to config a nickname and email, I registered `ssh-key` by the UIweb page.
3. use `ssh -p 29418 admin@localhost gerrit create-project --name example.git`
   I got a prompt: "Permission denied (publickkey)."
4. After searching from internet, I used `ssh -vv -p 29418 admin@localhost gerrit`

I got the following output:

```
gerrit2@bst-esa3-bs:~$ ssh -vv -p 29418 admin@localhost gerrit --help

OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu6, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: Applying options for *

debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0

debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 29418.

debug1: Connection established.

debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'

debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'

debug1: identity file /home/gerrit2/.ssh/id_rsa type 1

debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048

debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048

debug1: identity file /home/gerrit2/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1

debug1: identity file /home/gerrit2/.ssh/id_dsa type -1

debug1: identity file /home/gerrit2/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version GerritCodeReview_2.4.2 (SSHD-
CORE-0.5.1-R1095809)

debug1: no match: GerritCodeReview_2.4.2 (SSHD-CORE-0.5.1-R1095809)

debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu6

debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-
exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-
rsa,ssh-dss

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-
cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-
cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-
cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-
cbc@lysator.liu.se

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-
ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-
ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha1-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha1-96

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0

debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5

debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none

debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5

debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none

debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 138/256

debug2: bits set: 1040/2048

debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY

debug1: Host '[localhost]:29418' is known and matches the RSA host key.

debug1: Found key in /home/gerrit2/.ssh/known_hosts:1

debug2: bits set: 1018/2048

debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct

debug2: kex_derive_keys

debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

debug1: Roaming not allowed by server

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

debug2: key: /home/gerrit2/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f23f313aff0)

debug2: key: /home/gerrit2/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

debug1: Offering public key: /home/gerrit2/.ssh/id_rsa

debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey

debug1: Trying private key: /home/gerrit2/.ssh/id_dsa

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Mind editing all that into a code block? I would but it'd need approval and > 8 non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Christopher, thanks for remind. Done:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you upload your ssh key into Gerrit through the web interface?  Are you sure your username in Gerrit is 'admin'?

Comment: Brad, thank you, I did add my ssh key into gerrit, but it looks some problem with the hostname which I have no direction on how to resolve it.

Comment: In the gerrit webUI page of RSA key, it shows comments like "gerrit2@bst-esa3-bs", 'bst-esa3-bs' is my server name. But actually I was using the command: "ssh-keygen -t rsa". I guess the problem is the host name "bst-esa3-bs", because I can not use http://bst-esa3-bs to access gerrit via ie.

Comment: `
gerrit2@bst-esa3-bs:~$ ssh -p 29418 10.173.178.101:81 gerrit create-account --ssh-key - watcher

Permission denied (publickey).

gerrit2@bst-esa3-bs:~$ ssh -p 29418 gerrit2@localhost

Permission denied (publickey).

gerrit2@bst-esa3-bs:~$ ssh -p 29418 gerrit2@bst-esa3-bs

Permission denied (publickey).
`

Comment: is your username in the Gerrit web interface 'gerrit2'?  Make sure you are using the username Gerrit expects.  The key comment is ignored, so that won't impact anything.

Comment: Brad, Thanks for reply. My user name is admin which is created by the command "htpassword gerrit_site/etc/passwords admin", why my user name should be gerrit2?

Comment: Gerrit uses an internal user database.  It doesn't use the platform accounts.  Check to see what username Gerrit expects by looking at settings in the user interface.

Comment: Dear Brad,
Thanks for your patient support, eventually I found out the problem. It is caused by lacking initialization. Missing all-projects has been proved this I think.

The problem is caused when I was meeting the authorization problem I have changed the configuration of apache2 virtual host file to allow access all. That did make me be able to enter gerrit, but lack of initialization. I recreated the gerrit, problem resolved. I am now be able to create project, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The big gotcha, in my experience, is the ssh config file:
~/.ssh/config

This is where you tell SSH to align your user id with target URL and port.

```
Host gerrit.domain.com
    User my_user_name
    Port 29418
```

I only ever have to do this every few years, so always forget this last step after all the keys are setup and it still doesn't work.